# How do I validate a user input for conditions using grepl

Tags: r, error-handling, user-input, grepl

I am trying to stick to base R as a personal challenge. I'm not committed to using grepl though, it was just my first thought. And I've hit a roadblock.

Here is what I have so far:

```
armstrong <- function(x) {
if (grepl("^[-]{0,1}[0-9]{0,}.{0,1}[0-9]{1,}$", x) == FALSE) {
    stop("Please try submitting a valid number")
  } 
  else {
  temp <- strsplit(as.character(x), split = "")  
  y <- sapply(temp, function(y)sum(as.numeric(y)^length(y)))
  if (y == x) {
    print(paste("The number you entered,", x ,", is an Armstrong number"))
    }
  else {
    print(paste("The number you entered,", x ,", is not an Armstrong number"))
    }
  }
}

armstrong(readline(prompt = "Please enter a three digit positive number"))
```

The program checks to see if the user inputted an [Armstrong number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number). That part works. What I'm stuck on is the error handling for the user input. I can't get grepl to output FALSE if the user inputs a negative number, or if they input characters in between numbers, such as 1a4. It would be nice if grepl would output FALSE is the user inputs a number that isn't 3 digits, but that's not such a big deal because the function will still work.

How do I update the regular expressions to help with error handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just

```
if (! is.numeric(x) || x < 0) stop(…)
```

In other words: *use proper types*. Don’t accept a string if the input is supposed to be a number.

If you are required to accept a string, *convert that string to a number* and test whether the conversion succeeded. You can test for `NA` to check if it was successful.

I’d also suggest a few other changes to the function:

```
armstrong <- function (x) {
  num <- as.numeric(x)
  if (is.na(num) || num < 0) stop("Please try submitting a valid number")

  digits <- strsplit(x, "")[[1L]]
  sum <- sum(as.numeric(digits) ^ length(digits))
  msg <- paste0(
    "The number you entered, ", x, ", is ",
    if (num != sum) "not " else "",
    "an Armstrong number"
  )
  message(msg)
}
```

Comment: This is causing all my inputs to be erroneous. Even actual Armstrong numbers like 153

Comment: @speakwiththepen It’s impossible to diagnose this issue without the concrete code and example. `armstrong(153)` works for me with the change from my answer.

Comment: the issue is from the user prompt. `armstrong(readline(prompt = "Please enter a three digit positive number"))` entering 153 into the console gives the stop() message

Comment: @speakwiththepen Please refer to the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: after `armstrong(as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Please enter a three digit positive number")))` how do I test if the conversion worked? Let's say they entered 'abc'

Comment: @speakwiththepen You should be getting a warning about NA values. If you want to treat this warning as an error (good idea!), you can use `tryCatch(as.numeric(…), warning = stop)`. But at this point it might be a good idea to move this logic back into the function. Hang on …

Comment: @speakwiththepen Check the updated answer.

Comment: the updated answer works, thanks for taking the time! I'm trying to learn more about R. What is `[[1L]]` doing?

Comment: @speakwiththepen It’s just [normal subsetting](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html), to get the first list item. I’m using `1L` instead of `1` to make it extra clear that I’m using an *integer* (in R, `1` is a floating point number literal, which R then needs to convert into an integer internally before it can be used as a subsetting index).